# Writing to file, directory error

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string path = $@"C:\Journal";
    string fileName = @"";
    string compact = "";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fileName = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString() + ".txt";
        compact = (path + @"\" + fileName);        
    }

    private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(compact, true);
            myWriter.WriteLine(txtDisplay.Text);
            myWriter.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(compact, true);
            myWriter.WriteLine(txtDisplay.Text);
            myWriter.Close();
        }
}
```

I'm trying to write stuff from a multiline textbox into a file using the Monthly calender date as the file name. I keep getting an error that the directory does not exist. Not sure of the reason since i created the folder in the path, I appreciate the help.

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled
```

Comment: What line do you get the error on?

Comment: It seems that `C:\Journal` does not exists. `StreamWriter` can create a new file, but not the directory in which it should go

Comment: One possible reason is `/` in filename. Did you debug and check the value of filename variable?

Comment: What is the output of monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString()? If it contains "\", that is your problem. You need to replace any "\" with something else (maybe "-").

Comment: Always use `Path.Combine()` rather than concatenating paths manually. What's the value of `compact`?

Comment: @Kevin how exactly do i replace the "\"

Comment: monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString().Replace('\', '-')

Comment: @kevin it says too many string literals, not sure what i'm doing wrong

Comment: It works but only as showing dd.mm.yyyy as the name,i need it to show it with the selected dates

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have to *create directory*. Another issue is

```
  fileName = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString() + ".txt";
```

since *Short DateTime Format* can contain `'/'` or `'\'` which are forbidden within file names.

```
  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    // ToString(...) we don't want / or \ in the file's name
    fileName = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToString("dd'.'MM'.'yyyy") + ".txt";
    compact = Path.Combine(path, fileName);        
  }

  private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(compact));

    // Or File.AppendAllText(compact, txtDisplay.Text); 
    File.AppendAllLines(compact, new string[] {txtDisplay.Text});
  }
```